# How to define common operations between different objects in java?

Tags: java, operator-overloading, code-reuse

I have a number of operands of different types and want to define how
these operands can operate on each other. This seems like a generic
problem but I fail to find a good approach for implementing it.

Say for a start that I have scalars (i.e. numbers), matrix, and sets
of matrix or scalars and that I want to define the plus operation on these:

- scalar1.plus(scalar2) returns a scalar equal to scalar1+scalar2,
- matrix.plus(scalar1) or scalar.plus(matrix) both return a matrix
  where 'scalar1' each element has been added to each element of the
  matrix,
- matrixSet.plus(matrix1) returns a set where each matrix has been
  added to matrix1

And so on... Note that some operations may throw exceptions, such as
adding matrix of different sizes or adding sets that do not have the
same number of elements.

My goals are the following:

1- reuse as much code as possible (important because I will have many
     more operations and data types),

2- do as much validation at compile time as possible

3- make it easy to add new data types or operations in the future (for
     example, I may want to add a vector data type later on)

I initially thought I would define an Operand interface, which my
scalar, matrix, and set of these elements would implement, and which
would include methods like:

```
public Operand plus(Operand op);
```

This would allow be to define the plus operation from the bottom up,
starting with the simplest element (scalar):

```
public Operand plus(Operand operand) {
  if (Scalar.class.equals(operand.getClass())) {
    return new Scalar(this.value + ((Scalar) operand).getValue());
  } else {
   // assume the other operand will define the addition for me
   // since add is commutative
    return operand.plus(this);
  }
}
```

And then for matrix:

```
public Operand plus(Operand operand) {
  if (Scalar.class.equals(operand.getClass())) {
    // return a matrix where we add scalar value to all matrix elements
  } else if (Matrix.class.equals(operand.getClass())) {
    // return a matrix where we perform a scalar addition between each element
  } else {
    // assume the other operand will define the addition for me
    // since add is commutative
    return operand.plus(this);
  }
}
```

The idea being that whenever I introduce a new class implementing the
Operand type (say a vector), I will only have to define the plus
operation betwen that new operand and all the other existing
operands. I.e. I wouldn't have to rewrite the plus method of the
Scalar and Matrix classes.

This approach meets goals 1 and 3 but not 2: all operations return
Operand objects, and forces me to do a lot of casting and class
checking at run time, which doesn't seem like a good practice.

Any better way of approach my problem?

Comment: For starters, use the `instanceof` operator instead of `getClass()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth, I decided that I wasn't approaching the problem correctly by defining operations for each type of data that I created.  It just wasn't working well no matter what I tried.

What I ended up doing was to have one class per operation defined on integers.  E.g. Addition, Multiply, Addition8BitSat, etc.  In addition, I have one Evaluator class where I define how to derive an operation between two blocks, between a block and an integer, between sets of blocks and integer, etc. based on the result of the operations between on solely integers.

This approach addresses the three issues I listed above: zero redundancy in my code, methods that return results of the proper type, and easily expandable to other types.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). You will basically define a generic interface and then adapt the interface in as many ways as needed to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I did some reading on adapter patterns but still fail to understand how I would be using them in my present example. Would I be creating an adapter for each combination of data types? That seems like a lot! Would you mind giving me a concrete example of the interface and one or two adapters you would create for my proposed example?

Comment: @double07 Well if the data structure that you are implementing the operation on is the point of variation that you should likely consider making the data structure one of the parameters to say a constructor. At that point your program would polymorphically determine which adapter should be invoked in order to successfully carry out the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you're using the Operand interface at all. It seems like your main code-reuse technique is to call an operation on an operand when that operand has already defined the operation. But the use of an interface doesn't help you with that. What am I missing? Doesn't doing it this way involve the same amount of code, but allow nice things like specific return types and exceptions?

Scalar:

```
public Scalar plus(Scalar operand) {
    return new Scalar(this.value + operand.getValue());
}

public Matrix plus(Matrix operand) {
    return operand.plus(this);
}
```

Matrix:

```
public Operand plus(Scaler operand) {
    return new Scalar(this.value + operand.getValue());
}

public Operand plus(Matrix operand){
  // return matrix plus matrix
}
```

Comment: This is the first approach I thought of and might be what I use. The issue with it is that you double the code size since you need to define a separate method for each operand type and each operation in each class. This problem isn't obvious in the example above but imagine, say, 6 types of operands (matrix, scalar, vector, and their set counterpart) and you now have to write 6 plus methods for each of these operands: you lose the ability of have an Operand plus(Operand op) method that contains all the plus operation you would like to be leveraging. Again, that may be what I do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing this with java is defining operation methods in your data classes and overloading as necessary. If you have a matrix class, that class needs to know how to add another matrix to itself and a scalar to itself. I don't know if you have a particular reason for separating operands and operators but otherwise that's the right way to go. Here's some code to clarify the concept:

```
class Matrix{
  Matrix add(Matrix m){
    //add matrix to self
    return this;
  }
  Matrix add(Scalar s){
    //add scalar to self
    return this;
  }
}
```